# React Native - When "componentWillUnmount" will be called?

Tags: react-native

I'm using the [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) in order to navigate between pages.

When [Navigator.push()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#push) method is called, the "componentWillUnmount" method isn't called on the page we're navigating from.

It's a little bit problematic because I want to unsubscribe from listeners, etc.

Is it a normal behavior? 
When the "componentWillUnmount" is actually called?

Comment: It's not an anwer, but your question has been addressed a long time ago on GitHub, maybe you'll find an answer in this direction: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1025

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Navigator` uses stack to manager route. When you push a *new page*, current page wont unmount, if you pop from *new page* to the *current page*, the *new page* will unmount.
And in other scene, if you render some child component based on some regulation like `isLoading` or other, the `componentWillUnmount` method will also be called when they no longer need to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

In react-native, componentWillUnmount is not called as you would expect on the web. Instead try to use the navigation lifecycle, in whatever navigation library you are using (we are using react-navigation).