# How do I force a component to unmount when I navigate to a new page in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, lifecycle

I want to make sure the lifecycle method ComponentWillUnmount fires when I navigate to a new page.  I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241083/how-to-remove-or-unmount-a-component-in-react-native), but that doesn't seem to mention anything about navigating to a new page.  I also found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647087/react-native-when-componentwillunmount-will-be-called) but I'm using react-navigation.  In addition, I'm not using pop/push.  I'm simply using this.props.navigation.navigate('SomePage') to get to the next page

Comment: Is there something you want to do, or a function you want to call in `componentWillUnmount`? Or are you trying to remove the previous page?

Comment: There are a few methods that remove bluetooth listeners.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `this.props.navigation.replace('routName');`
It will do your job.

Comment: I did that to display a screen that include a webview, the webview crash and then I see my component still mounted.

Answer (score 8):

React navigation never destroys the screen. It means your screen will never unmount or when you go back it will never remount (`didMount`). To do such you have to use `useFocusEffect`

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Home = () => {
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      // Do something when the screen is focused/mount

      return () => {
        // Do something when the screen is unfocused/unmount
        // Useful for cleanup functions
      };
    }, [])
  );

  return <Home />;
}
```

Reference : Navigation Lifecycle

Answer (score 3):

Checkout `React Navigation`'s ways to handle a component's lifecycle event [in their docs here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html)

TL;DR, you can checkout [`React Navigation`'s navigation lifecycle event](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) to perform actions when you switch screens. Hope it helps.

Comment: There's no mention of the word "unmount" in those links ...